# Meteor returning a field from MongoDB works in console but not in application

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to read out a file in my [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) database. In the console the response is correct while in my application I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'iati' of undefined

I defined a template helper which should return a certain sub-field within my MongoDB collection. However the following does not seem to work (I get the beforementioned error).

```
 Template.hello.helpers({
    test: function() {
        return Test.findOne().iati;
    }
});
```

What does seem to work is to return the entire object:

```
 Template.hello.helpers({
    test: function() {
        return Test.findOne();
    }
});
```

And then call the specific field within the template:

```
{{test.iati}}
```

However, I want to use the data within the JavaScript script. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your helper function is run before the client has received the documents in the collections. `Test.findOne()` will evaluate to  `undefined`, which doesn't have the property `iati` (according to your error message). When your helper instead returns the results of `Test.findOne()` and you use `{{test.iati}}` in your template, `{{test.iati}}` will only show `test.iati` if `test` has the property `iati` (otherwise it won't show anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection methods like `Tests.findOne()` return the documents that are already fetched to the client's Minimongo copy. Before your document is fetched, `findOne()` will return null.

To safeguard against this, simply check the result in the helper before you proceed with the calculation:

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  test: function() {
    if(! Test.findOne()) return;
    return Test.findOne().iati;
  },
});
```

You can also wait for the subscription in the Iron Router to ensure the proper documents are loaded:

```
this.route('routeName', {
  ...
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    this.subscribe('subscriptionName').wait();
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```